# C# COM Interop Excel: Preserving Leading Zeros In Text Strings

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, interop, com-interop

I am outputting an Excel worksheet that contains **strings** of the form hh:mm:ss.  However, Excel is seeing fit to delete any leading zeros even though they are text.  I tried myRange.NumberFormat = "@" but this results in bizarre decimal representations.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked too soon.  Setting range.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss" did the trick without affecting the other strings in that column.